# Bean-Injection failed at Hazelcast map-store class

Tags: spring, dictionary, persistence, hazelcast

I wanna inject a bean which will persist the map-entries at hazelcast.

```
<map name="storethiselements-map">
<backup-count>1</backup-count>
<map-store enabled="true">
<class-name>name.of.MapPersistenceObject</class-name>
<write-delay-seconds>0</write-delay-seconds>
</map-store>
</map>
```

These are constructor-args for the hazelcast-instance. 
In the MapPersistenceObject there exists a Service which is responsible for persisting the entries. I have marked MapPersistenceObject as component and made the Service-Object Autowired so that Spring will inject the right Service-Bean with the right Datasource.

I have tried this but i get a NullPointer where the Service should be injected. It seems to me that Spring can't connect or autowire the MapPersistenceObject with the Service. It looks like this:

```
@Component
public class MapPersistenceObject implements
    MapLoader<Long, DeviceWakeupAction>, MapStore<Long, DeviceWakeupAction> {
@Autowired
StoreMapEntries storeMapEntriesService;
    [...]
```

Maybe somebody knows a solution of the problem?

regards && tia
  noircc

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use Spring configuration, not Hazelcast xml configuration.

```
<hz:hazelcast id="hazelcast">
    <hz:config>
        ...
        <hz:map name="storethiselements-map" backup-count="1">
            <hz:map-store enabled="true" implementation="mapPersistenceObject" write-delay-seconds="0"/>
        </hz:map>
        ...
    </hz:config>
</hz:hazelcast>

<bean id="mapPersistenceObject" class="name.of.MapPersistenceObject"/>
```

See [Hazelcast Spring integration](http://www.hazelcast.com/docs/2.0/manual/single_html/#SpringIntegration).

Comment: I am using hazelcast spring integration, and its failing with nullpointer exception on start up,   this is my configuration, can you please help me.  `<hz:map name="newsMap" backup-count="2" max-size="0"
    eviction-percentage="30" read-backup-data="true" eviction-policy="NONE"
    merge-policy="com.hazelcast.map.merge.PassThroughMergePolicy" />`

Comment: I found it a bit disappointing that defining `hz:map` won't automagically put it in Spring context, you still need to `getMap("myMap")` from HazelcastInstance. Am I missing something?